# How to query AD within SSH key-based authentication session?

Tags: windows, ssh, security, openssh, authentication

I have a PoSh script on a Windows (2019) server that I want to kick off from a simple web app (a button) on a linux webserver, so I enabled OpenSSH and restricted it to just a generic, unprivileged account.

In manual testing with username/password authentication, the account authenticates and the script runs just fine.

When I established a public/private key pair, the account connects, but the script fails.  The failure is when the script tries to read the (null) results of a necessary ADSI query. I thought one of the reasons to use key pairs was to avoid the need for hard-coding passwords into scripts.

The only thing I can imagine is that key-based authentication isn't really "logging in" and that there needs to be some kind of ticket generated that can be passed on to AD when credentials are needed for security access checks. I would think that a caveat like that would be explained somewhere in all the documentation about setting up/using SSH on Windows.

If my guess is true, what is the best way to resolve this?  Is there some setting in OpenSSH so key-based authentication generate a ticket without a password?  Do I really need to put the password into code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only thing I can imagine is that key-based authentication isn't really "logging in" and that there needs to be some kind of ticket generated that can be passed on to AD when credentials are needed for security access checks

Credentials are always needed to access AD. In normal logins, ADSI (as well as RSAT, SMB file sharing, etc) automatically uses your "default" credentials that Windows has stored as part of the login process – for Active Directory it obtains a [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) initial ticket from the AD DC (as well as storing your NTLM password hash for non-AD-integrated services). You can run `klist` to see the "krbtgt/" ticket which grants access to all AD services.

> Is there some setting in OpenSSH so key-based authentication generate a ticket without a password?

Generally no, the machine cannot *generate* tickets from nothing – it has to *obtain* them from the AD DC, and to do this it needs your credentials in a form acceptable to AD. This usually means your password (or technically your PKI certificate if AD is set up for that – but that isn't going to work through OpenSSH).

With public-key authentication, OpenSSH on the server doesn't have any credentials it could use to obtain a Kerberos ticket on your behalf.

An exception to this is *constrained delegation* using the "S4U2Proxy" extension of Kerberos, where the system *could* use its own 'machine' credentials to generate tickets impersonating you. This wouldn't be an OpenSSH setting however (S4U2Proxy cannot be used to create "initial" krbtgt tickets as far as I know); once permissions for constrained delegation are granted to the machine, it's likely ADSI that would need to ask Windows to do it for the actual LDAP connection.

> I would think that a caveat like that would be explained somewhere in all the documentation about setting up/using SSH on Windows.

It's likely assumed to be "already known" from PowerShell Remoting via WinRM, where it has been known as the "second hop problem" for as long as the feature existed.

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.1

Out of the options offered, the SSH transport supports unconstrained Kerberos delegation, but not CredSSP (though I can't see why the article claims the latter is more secure – they both are transfer your credentials so both are equally risky).

This is not a problem unique to Windows – it is seen on Unix sites as well, e.g. universities running systems where users have NFS- or AFS-based home directories find it impossible to use public-key auth for the same reason.

> Do I really need to put the password into code?

Of course not – you can put it in a separate config file instead.

(There is little difference between having a file with a private key in it, vs a file with a password in it... in the end both of them are static, non-expiring credentials that can be stolen, and both have to be protected to the same extent. It's the *other* features of keypairs that make them worth using.)

Another option would be to rewrite your script to run on Linux, accessing Active Directory through LDAP (e.g. python-ldap or perl Net::LDAP). That way, instead of storing a password, it could use a Kerberos keytab file for authentication – which *still* needs the same protection on disk, but does have the advantage of using Kerberos in general.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, if the OpenSSH server was configured to accept public-key authentication, then it would essentially replace the Kerberos (password) based authentication.  Note: You can configure your OpenSSH Server to accept your AD directory Kerberos based authentication.  In order to achieve that on Linux, a trust relationship would have to be made between IPA and AD, I have rolled out a network that uses IPA and AD and I am able to connect to RHEL servers using `"username@ad.domain"@linux.host` syntax without entering a password. i.e. *I connect from Windows to the Linux server.*

Comment: @user1686 That is an informative answer, thanks!  I can't rewrite the script on Linux in part because I'm not skilled enough, and in part because the script needs to print to a receipt printer that is in a non-Linux-friendly configuration for other needs.